# why is python's parser throwing errors on this simple input?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following code -

```
from sys import version

class ExampleClass(object):
        def get_sys_version(self):
                return version

x = ExampleClass()
print x.get_sys_version()
```

and it gets parsed by this code -

```
import ast

source = open("input.py")
code = source.read()
node = ast.parse(code, mode='eval')
```

and results in this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 5, in <module>
    node = ast.parse(code, mode='eval')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    from sys import version
```

This appears to be a very simple file to parse - it certainly runs - why does the parser throw this error?

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Answer (score 11):

This is because you're using `mode='eval'`, which only works for single expressions. Your code has multiple statements, so use `mode='exec'` instead. (It's the default)

See the [documentation for `compile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile) for explanation of the `mode` argument, since that's what `ast.parse()` uses.

Answer (score -1):

It's not related to `ast`.

You get same error, when try:

```
In [1]: eval('from sys import version')
  File "<string>", line 1
    from sys import version
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Try `exec` mode:

```
In [1]: exec('from sys import version')

In [2]:
```